# An inequality on curvature at à specific point

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Let $c:I\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ be an arc length parameterized curve. Assume also that $c$ stays inside a disk of radius $r$ and at sone $t_0$, $|c(t_0)|=r $.

I have shown that $c(t)$ and $c''(t)$ are collinear but I'm having trouble showing that the curvature at $t_0$ verifies  $\lvert \rho(t_0)\rvert \geq \dfrac{1}{r}$.

Any ideas on how to get there? I think I need to différentiate but I can't seem to get thé right result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that the curvature of $c$ at $c(t_0)$ is bigger than that of the circle.

After a translation and rotation, assume that $c(t_0)$ is the origin and the circle is given by 
$$ x^2 + (y-r)^2 = r^2.$$
(So it touches the origin from above). Assume that $c$ and the circle are locally given by

$$ (x, f_1(x)), (x, f_2(x))$$

respectively, so that $f_i(0) = f'_i(0) = 0$ for $i=1,2$. The assuption that $c$ is inside the circle gives $f_1(x) \ge f_2(x)$. All these imply $f{''}_1(0)\ge f_2^{''}(0)\ge 0$. (See remark)

The curvature of a graph is given by ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_a_graph))

$$\kappa_i = \frac{|f_i^{''}|}{(1+ f_i')^{\frac 32}}.$$

Thus at the origin we have

$$ \kappa_1 = |f_1^{''}(0)| = f_1^{''}(0)\ge f_2^{''}(0) = \kappa_2 = \frac 1r.$$

**Remark**: Consider $g = f_1 - f_2$. Then $g(0) = g'(0) =0$ and $g(x)\ge 0$. This imply $g''(0)\ge 0$: If not, then $g''(0) = -\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon >0$. By definition, there is $\delta>0$ so that

$$ \frac{g'(x) - g'(0)}{x} < -\frac{\epsilon}{2} x $$

for all $x$ with $0<x<\delta$. This implies $g'(x) < \frac{\epsilon}{2} x$ and so

$$ g(x) = \int_0^x g'(s) ds < -\frac{\epsilon}{2} \int_0^x sds = -\frac{\epsilon}{4} x^2 <0$$

for all $0<x<\delta$, which is a contradiction. Thus $f_1^{''}(0)\ge f_2^{''}(0)$. That $f_2^{''}(0) \ge 0$ is a directly calculation ($f_2$ represents the circle).

Comment: I don't see why “all these” implies the inequality of the second derivatives.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Please see the edit.